# Problem migrating the parsing of an xml from T-SQL to postgres

Tags: xml, postgresql

I am having problems when "migrating" my query in which I parse a column with XML stored in it, I am "migrating" from T-SQL to Postgres, since my current development requires it.

My query in T-SQL, takes a column that contains XML that are retrieved from another system, I create the prefixes for the xml with the "XMLNAMESPACES" and then I do an INSERT INTO to save the query in a previously created table, with the subquery I "choose" the values ​​or "columns" that I want to return, cast them and rename them at the same time. After this I cast the "XML" column to "XML" and it is already in "VARCHAR" and finally the .nodes function is called to return the table derived from the query

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4' AS cfdi, 
                    'http://www.sat.gob.mx/Pagos20' AS pago20, 
                    'http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital' AS tfd)

INSERT INTO [CFDI_SON990511MI0_RECIBIDOS].[dbo].[DataXml_SON990511MI0_RepsRecibidos_2023] (UUID, DoctoRelacionado, NumParcialidad, ImpPagado, FePago)

SELECT 
        prx4_0.*
FROM
(
    SELECT 
            UUID,
            x.value('(@IdDocumento)', 'NVARCHAR(64)') AS DoctoRelacionado,
            x.value('(@NumParcialidad)', 'TINYINT') AS NumParcialidad,
            x.value('(@ImpPagado)', 'DECIMAL(26, 8)') AS ImpPagado,
            x.value('(/cfdi:Comprobante/@Fecha)[1]', 'DATETIME') AS FePago
    FROM [dbo].[XML]
    
    --El casteo ocurre aqui
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST(XML AS XML)) A(TheXml)

    --Se llama a la funcion .nodes para retornar la tabla derivada de la consulta
    CROSS APPLY TheXml.nodes('/cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Complemento/pago20:Pagos/pago20:Pago/pago20:DoctoRelacionado') B(x)
) prx4_0
GO
```

This is the XML to be able to reproduce:

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (UUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY, xmldata NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @tbl (UUID, xmldata) VALUES
('AAA1ADA1-9151-4C90-AA62-43590DCC7C81', 
        N'<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv33.xsd
            http://www.sat.gob.mx/Pagos http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/Pagos/Pagos10.xsd" 
            LugarExpedicion="37480" TipoDeComprobante="P" Total="0" Moneda="XXX" Certificado="MIIG" 
            SubTotal="0" NoCertificado="00001000000504465028" Sello="V1" Fecha="2023-01-09T17:09:53" Version="3.3" 
            xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" xmlns:pago10="http://www.sat.gob.mx/Pagos">
        <cfdi:Emisor Rfc="CARE891026810" Nombre="MARIA ELIZABETH CHAVEZ RAMIREZ" RegimenFiscal="621"></cfdi:Emisor>
        <cfdi:Receptor Rfc="SON990511MI0" Nombre="SONIGAS SA DE CV" UsoCFDI="P01"></cfdi:Receptor>
        <cfdi:Conceptos>
            <cfdi:Concepto ClaveProdServ="84111506" Cantidad="1" ClaveUnidad="ACT" Descripcion="Pago" ValorUnitario="0" Importe="0"></cfdi:Concepto>
        </cfdi:Conceptos>
        <cfdi:Complemento>
            <pago10:Pagos Version="1.0">
                <pago10:Pago FechaPago="2022-12-27T00:00:00" FormaDePagoP="03" MonedaP="MXN" Monto="31508.65">
                    <pago10:DoctoRelacionado IdDocumento="AAA1D7E6-23AD-44FC-A544-9CB47D9CFCCD" MonedaDR="MXN" MetodoDePagoDR="PPD" NumParcialidad="1" ImpSaldoAnt="999.99" ImpPagado="999.99" ImpSaldoInsoluto="0"></pago10:DoctoRelacionado>
                    <pago10:DoctoRelacionado IdDocumento="AAA124C5-48FC-4409-BB76-8A23BF6318F3" MonedaDR="MXN" MetodoDePagoDR="PPD" NumParcialidad="1" ImpSaldoAnt="6904.91" ImpPagado="6904.91" ImpSaldoInsoluto="0"></pago10:DoctoRelacionado>
                    <pago10:DoctoRelacionado IdDocumento="AAA17CA8-222A-4146-A943-58AAFD62C7F3" MonedaDR="MXN" MetodoDePagoDR="PPD" NumParcialidad="1" ImpSaldoAnt="2284.99" ImpPagado="2284.99" ImpSaldoInsoluto="0"></pago10:DoctoRelacionado>
                    <pago10:DoctoRelacionado IdDocumento="AAA111BC-4CE8-4572-8C75-2D673F1ED9F4" MonedaDR="MXN" MetodoDePagoDR="PPD" NumParcialidad="1" ImpSaldoAnt="1800.00" ImpPagado="1800.00" ImpSaldoInsoluto="0"></pago10:DoctoRelacionado>
                    <pago10:DoctoRelacionado IdDocumento="AAA1686A-7605-423D-809F-A6EE240E9587" MonedaDR="MXN" MetodoDePagoDR="PPD" NumParcialidad="1" ImpSaldoAnt="3229.99" ImpPagado="3229.99" ImpSaldoInsoluto="0"></pago10:DoctoRelacionado>
                    <pago10:DoctoRelacionado IdDocumento="AAA1783C-A24A-4DC6-8A87-54591E555CCE" MonedaDR="MXN" MetodoDePagoDR="PPD" NumParcialidad="1" ImpSaldoAnt="2599.99" ImpPagado="2599.99" ImpSaldoInsoluto="0"></pago10:DoctoRelacionado>
                    <pago10:DoctoRelacionado IdDocumento="AAA17618-B009-4A80-8C12-CF7F697A512E" MonedaDR="MXN" MetodoDePagoDR="PPD" NumParcialidad="1" ImpSaldoAnt="3167.95" ImpPagado="3167.95" ImpSaldoInsoluto="0"></pago10:DoctoRelacionado>
                    <pago10:DoctoRelacionado IdDocumento="AAA1DBB5-B99E-4BFB-AD27-FC249EDEEBCE" MonedaDR="MXN" MetodoDePagoDR="PPD" NumParcialidad="1" ImpSaldoAnt="2972.86" ImpPagado="2972.86" ImpSaldoInsoluto="0"></pago10:DoctoRelacionado>
                    <pago10:DoctoRelacionado IdDocumento="AAA19C00-65FB-4E83-9AD7-2EF660694ECF" MonedaDR="MXN" MetodoDePagoDR="PPD" NumParcialidad="1" ImpSaldoAnt="4629.99" ImpPagado="4629.99" ImpSaldoInsoluto="0"></pago10:DoctoRelacionado>
                    <pago10:DoctoRelacionado IdDocumento="AAA1CD78-9581-4F43-8741-8C9506E26B2C" MonedaDR="MXN" MetodoDePagoDR="PPD" NumParcialidad="1" ImpSaldoAnt="2739.99" ImpPagado="2739.99" ImpSaldoInsoluto="0"></pago10:DoctoRelacionado>
                </pago10:Pago>
            </pago10:Pagos>
            <registrofiscal:CFDIRegistroFiscal xmlns:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/registrofiscal http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/cfdiregistrofiscal/cfdiregistrofiscal.xsd" Version="1.0" Folio="2301200000009898" xmlns:registrofiscal="http://www.sat.gob.mx/registrofiscal">
            </registrofiscal:CFDIRegistroFiscal>
            <tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/TimbreFiscalDigital/TimbreFiscalDigitalv11.xsd" Version="1.1" UUID="AAA1ADA1-9151-4C90-AA62-43590DCC7C81" FechaTimbrado="2023-01-09T17:20:57" RfcProvCertif="SAT970701NN3" SelloCFD="V1cULko9bjPwFcWBsjJbPDHo92KXkK2VT12bxm9F+9XiiD4oNDE3mpLaf4L1iKndhotlcx14MphlBAfRBRm/ue+eR6YAR+v+t3ZLXpD0QzhJzKCF0WSIkt7kDMhJmroYluMs+D2GwELC9t/LxhmjY5k5OyEBoQm75hfD1EpfN+j1MzZrRj/DuLLp4oVnb64/wfwKmJ0BxtsR7Dwpe7Q/SvuR7W3GnuRIqL/gFKBfsH7qW9fP+4owoX2iERCX5RWIt+yVOejOGMPlMzE7pdihEuulq32aGV1AlyZNqKG9FukbOnSqRJnZdqmz/VqufWEC1h7C8S105tCuDGfldyDy4Q==" NoCertificadoSAT="00001000000504465028" SelloSAT="U09+TX0gGO45iDdPi0gN9CttScMvfj5G7OF8biKdijrPIWSNO7PzYdoGauKvOP6UCgW/x8MpRN+TfoVvdVEmpFrQC1jD7dpbAqWTeh+q1Qsb+5dm3lbgHxp3ImHACR7DORIxOadF/1oj6s0t69UGkTmsDOs90uVDsLL8RWf/yKTwRN+PpSdqy3FCHLMMOfZKZM76xjIVPQT6Hl2n8HhtaBTL/CiKb095wHTl/mXfX5u7UNlOoUUsG2wMeo+lJOqf5e0M0cJ4V3t5Cqr8ZhZu6atLDBqTSDpDSbJh1f3H9OLqoOTMgzSLkmU0jA+Q0TdknP7ujhkZPK2c/gJaJO91Cw==" />
        </cfdi:Complemento>
    </cfdi:Comprobante>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end
```

and this is my current code in PostgreSQL:

```
WITH
    XMLNAMESPACES AS (
        SELECT 
            'http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3' AS cfdi, 
            'http://www.sat.gob.mx/Pagos' AS pago10, 
            'http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital' AS tfd,
            'http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/cfdiregistrofiscal/cfdiregistrofiscal.xsd' AS registrofiscal)
            
     SELECT 
        "UUID"
        , unnest(xpath('/cfdi:Comprobante/@Serie',"XML"::xml , '{{cfdi, http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3}}')::varchar[]) AS cfd_serie
    from public."Pago_XML";
```

This is the error I get when I want to perform the query:

> SQL Error [2200M]: ERROR: could not parse XML document¶  Detail: line 1: xmlns:schemaLocation: 'http://www.sat.gob.mx/registrofiscal [http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/cfdiregistrofiscal/cfdiregistrofiscal.xsd'](http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/cfdiregistrofiscal/cfdiregistrofiscal.xsd%27) is not a valid URI¶p://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/cfdiregistrofiscal/cfdiregistrofiscal.xsd"¶

I was already investigating my table already generated in T-SQL, it does not give me this error and it is not possible for me to make a replacement for that "URI" since the table is from a provider. I would greatly appreciate any help, if you need more information about the XML, table or query I can provide it.

This my actual table on T-SQL and and it is also the output I expect with the postgres query

| UUID | FePago | DoctoRelacionado | NumParcialidad | ImpPagado |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0009034a-3feb-4b2e-88fa-4605e5c6a7d4 | 2023-01-20 12:00:00.000 | EE98EEDA-915B-B34D-8FFF-DD7FA49E2490 | 1 | 287124.37000000 |
| 0010D6C2-AB5E-45F5-B8AB-5EE57C79BAE8 | 2022-12-28 12:00:00.000 | FADF8224-0D47-48E6-B8A4-362861D9EB00 | 1 | 16923.24000000 |
| 00157E99-984B-42A0-BA55-D57D76E9155E | 2023-04-26 12:00:00.000 | D912107F-C1E9-4078-8F8D-7D954446CF8A | 1 | 14160.70000000 |

T-SQL VERSION (SELECT @@VERSION)

```
version                                                   |
----------------------------------------------------------|
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB5029377) - 15.0.2104.1 (X64)   Aug 16 2023 00:09:21   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 19045: ) (Hypervisor)|
```

Postgres version (SELECT version();)

```
version                                                   |
----------------------------------------------------------|
PostgreSQL 15.3, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit|
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your RDBMS and its version.

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit the question in a moment. @Yitzhak Khabinsky

Comment: Your question isn't about T-SQL, it's about PostgreSQL; you would be better off explaining what your T-SQL does so that those *not fluent* in it, and are fluent in PostgreSQL can help you. Otherwise those fluent in one but not the other are likely not able to help, but you're attracting both.

Comment: @Thom A. Thanks, I'm editing the question again explaining the T-SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are incorrect `xsi:schemaLocation` values in the XML.

I had to remove them from the XML.

PostgreSQL XML shredding is similar to Oracle implementation.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Wnc4WtX1)

**Postres SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
CREATE TABLE tbl (ID UUID PRIMARY KEY, xmldata VARCHAR(8192));
INSERT INTO tbl (ID, xmldata) VALUES
('AAA1ADA1-9151-4C90-AA62-43590DCC7C81', 
  '<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  LugarExpedicion="37480" TipoDeComprobante="P" Total="0"
                  Moneda="XXX" Certificado="MIIG" SubTotal="0"
                  NoCertificado="00001000000504465028" Sello="V1"
                  Fecha="2023-01-09T17:09:53" Version="3.3"
                  xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3"
                  xmlns:pago10="http://www.sat.gob.mx/Pagos">
    <cfdi:Emisor Rfc="CARE891026810" Nombre="MARIA ELIZABETH CHAVEZ RAMIREZ"
                 RegimenFiscal="621"></cfdi:Emisor>
    <cfdi:Receptor Rfc="SON990511MI0" Nombre="SONIGAS SA DE CV" UsoCFDI="P01"></cfdi:Receptor>
    <cfdi:Conceptos>
        <cfdi:Concepto ClaveProdServ="84111506" Cantidad="1" ClaveUnidad="ACT"
                       Descripcion="Pago" ValorUnitario="0" Importe="0"></cfdi:Concepto>
    </cfdi:Conceptos>
    <cfdi:Complemento>
        <pago10:Pagos Version="1.0">
            <pago10:Pago FechaPago="2022-12-27T00:00:00" FormaDePagoP="03"
                         MonedaP="MXN" Monto="31508.65">
                <pago10:DoctoRelacionado IdDocumento="AAA1D7E6-23AD-44FC-A544-9CB47D9CFCCD"
                                         MonedaDR="MXN" MetodoDePagoDR="PPD"
                                         NumParcialidad="1" ImpSaldoAnt="999.99"
                                         ImpPagado="999.99" ImpSaldoInsoluto="0"></pago10:DoctoRelacionado>
                <pago10:DoctoRelacionado IdDocumento="AAA124C5-48FC-4409-BB76-8A23BF6318F3"
                                         MonedaDR="MXN" MetodoDePagoDR="PPD"
                                         NumParcialidad="1"
                                         ImpSaldoAnt="6904.91"
                                         ImpPagado="6904.91"
                                         ImpSaldoInsoluto="0"></pago10:DoctoRelacionado>
                <pago10:DoctoRelacionado IdDocumento="AAA17CA8-222A-4146-A943-58AAFD62C7F3"
                                         MonedaDR="MXN" MetodoDePagoDR="PPD"
                                         NumParcialidad="1"
                                         ImpSaldoAnt="2284.99"
                                         ImpPagado="2284.99"
                                         ImpSaldoInsoluto="0"></pago10:DoctoRelacionado>
                <pago10:DoctoRelacionado IdDocumento="AAA111BC-4CE8-4572-8C75-2D673F1ED9F4"
                                         MonedaDR="MXN" MetodoDePagoDR="PPD"
                                         NumParcialidad="1"
                                         ImpSaldoAnt="1800.00"
                                         ImpPagado="1800.00"
                                         ImpSaldoInsoluto="0"></pago10:DoctoRelacionado>
                <pago10:DoctoRelacionado IdDocumento="AAA1686A-7605-423D-809F-A6EE240E9587"
                                         MonedaDR="MXN" MetodoDePagoDR="PPD"
                                         NumParcialidad="1"
                                         ImpSaldoAnt="3229.99"
                                         ImpPagado="3229.99"
                                         ImpSaldoInsoluto="0"></pago10:DoctoRelacionado>
                <pago10:DoctoRelacionado IdDocumento="AAA1783C-A24A-4DC6-8A87-54591E555CCE"
                                         MonedaDR="MXN" MetodoDePagoDR="PPD"
                                         NumParcialidad="1"
                                         ImpSaldoAnt="2599.99"
                                         ImpPagado="2599.99"
                                         ImpSaldoInsoluto="0"></pago10:DoctoRelacionado>
                <pago10:DoctoRelacionado IdDocumento="AAA17618-B009-4A80-8C12-CF7F697A512E"
                                         MonedaDR="MXN" MetodoDePagoDR="PPD"
                                         NumParcialidad="1"
                                         ImpSaldoAnt="3167.95"
                                         ImpPagado="3167.95"
                                         ImpSaldoInsoluto="0"></pago10:DoctoRelacionado>
                <pago10:DoctoRelacionado IdDocumento="AAA1DBB5-B99E-4BFB-AD27-FC249EDEEBCE"
                                         MonedaDR="MXN" MetodoDePagoDR="PPD"
                                         NumParcialidad="1"
                                         ImpSaldoAnt="2972.86"
                                         ImpPagado="2972.86"
                                         ImpSaldoInsoluto="0"></pago10:DoctoRelacionado>
                <pago10:DoctoRelacionado IdDocumento="AAA19C00-65FB-4E83-9AD7-2EF660694ECF"
                                         MonedaDR="MXN" MetodoDePagoDR="PPD"
                                         NumParcialidad="1"
                                         ImpSaldoAnt="4629.99"
                                         ImpPagado="4629.99"
                                         ImpSaldoInsoluto="0"></pago10:DoctoRelacionado>
                <pago10:DoctoRelacionado IdDocumento="AAA1CD78-9581-4F43-8741-8C9506E26B2C"
                                         MonedaDR="MXN" MetodoDePagoDR="PPD"
                                         NumParcialidad="1"
                                         ImpSaldoAnt="2739.99"
                                         ImpPagado="2739.99"
                                         ImpSaldoInsoluto="0"></pago10:DoctoRelacionado>
            </pago10:Pago>
        </pago10:Pagos>
        <registrofiscal:CFDIRegistroFiscal Version="1.0"
                                           Folio="2301200000009898"
                                           xmlns:registrofiscal="http://www.sat.gob.mx/registrofiscal">
        </registrofiscal:CFDIRegistroFiscal>
        <tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital"
                                 Version="1.1"
                                 UUID="AAA1ADA1-9151-4C90-AA62-43590DCC7C81"
                                 FechaTimbrado="2023-01-09T17:20:57"
                                 RfcProvCertif="SAT970701NN3"
                                 SelloCFD="V1cULko9bjPwFcWBsjJbPDHo92KXkK2VT12bxm9F+9XiiD4oNDE3mpLaf4L1iKndhotlcx14MphlBAfRBRm/ue+eR6YAR+v+t3ZLXpD0QzhJzKCF0WSIkt7kDMhJmroYluMs+D2GwELC9t/LxhmjY5k5OyEBoQm75hfD1EpfN+j1MzZrRj/DuLLp4oVnb64/wfwKmJ0BxtsR7Dwpe7Q/SvuR7W3GnuRIqL/gFKBfsH7qW9fP+4owoX2iERCX5RWIt+yVOejOGMPlMzE7pdihEuulq32aGV1AlyZNqKG9FukbOnSqRJnZdqmz/VqufWEC1h7C8S105tCuDGfldyDy4Q=="
                                 NoCertificadoSAT="00001000000504465028"
                                 SelloSAT="U09+TX0gGO45iDdPi0gN9CttScMvfj5G7OF8biKdijrPIWSNO7PzYdoGauKvOP6UCgW/x8MpRN+TfoVvdVEmpFrQC1jD7dpbAqWTeh+q1Qsb+5dm3lbgHxp3ImHACR7DORIxOadF/1oj6s0t69UGkTmsDOs90uVDsLL8RWf/yKTwRN+PpSdqy3FCHLMMOfZKZM76xjIVPQT6Hl2n8HhtaBTL/CiKb095wHTl/mXfX5u7UNlOoUUsG2wMeo+lJOqf5e0M0cJ4V3t5Cqr8ZhZu6atLDBqTSDpDSbJh1f3H9OLqoOTMgzSLkmU0jA+Q0TdknP7ujhkZPK2c/gJaJO91Cw=="/>
    </cfdi:Complemento>
</cfdi:Comprobante>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ID, t.* 
FROM tbl
  , XMLTABLE(
        xmlnamespaces('http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3' as "cfdi",
            'http://www.sat.gob.mx/Pagos' as "pago10"),
       '/cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Complemento/pago10:Pagos/pago10:Pago/pago10:DoctoRelacionado'
       PASSING XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT tbl.xmldata)
       COLUMNS 
               IdDocumento varchar(64) PATH '@IdDocumento',
             NumParcialida int         PATH '@NumParcialidad'
) as t;
```

**Output**

| id | iddocumento | numparcialida |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa1ada1-9151-4c90-aa62-43590dcc7c81 | AAA1D7E6-23AD-44FC-A544-9CB47D9CFCCD | 1 |
| aaa1ada1-9151-4c90-aa62-43590dcc7c81 | AAA124C5-48FC-4409-BB76-8A23BF6318F3 | 1 |
| aaa1ada1-9151-4c90-aa62-43590dcc7c81 | AAA17CA8-222A-4146-A943-58AAFD62C7F3 | 1 |
| aaa1ada1-9151-4c90-aa62-43590dcc7c81 | AAA111BC-4CE8-4572-8C75-2D673F1ED9F4 | 1 |
| aaa1ada1-9151-4c90-aa62-43590dcc7c81 | AAA1686A-7605-423D-809F-A6EE240E9587 | 1 |
| aaa1ada1-9151-4c90-aa62-43590dcc7c81 | AAA1783C-A24A-4DC6-8A87-54591E555CCE | 1 |
| aaa1ada1-9151-4c90-aa62-43590dcc7c81 | AAA17618-B009-4A80-8C12-CF7F697A512E | 1 |
| aaa1ada1-9151-4c90-aa62-43590dcc7c81 | AAA1DBB5-B99E-4BFB-AD27-FC249EDEEBCE | 1 |
| aaa1ada1-9151-4c90-aa62-43590dcc7c81 | AAA19C00-65FB-4E83-9AD7-2EF660694ECF | 1 |
| aaa1ada1-9151-4c90-aa62-43590dcc7c81 | AAA1CD78-9581-4F43-8741-8C9506E26B2C | 1 |

Comment: Thank you very much, @Yitzhak Khabinsky, but I have a question, is the elimination of "xsi:schemaLocation values" always applied? Since I have 73 rows with this "schemaLocation"

Comment: The sample XML is not well-formed because of the erroneous "xsi:schemaLocation values". All of them need to be fixed, or removed like I did. That's why it is better to use XML data type column in the database instead of varchar(...) data type

Comment: Thanks again. The query works, but I had to remove this entire string:xmlns:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/registrofiscal http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/cfdiregistrofiscal/cfdiregistrofiscal.xsd"xmlns:schemaLocation="

Comment: I have updated the answer, since I had a detail that I did not expect, an apology for disturbing again.